# Find Intersection of two Multipolygon

Tags: postgis, postgresql, polygon, sql, geometry

I have two tables from Open Baltimore Dataset - [Vital Signs (Housing and Community Development)](http://bniajfi.org/vital_signs/data_downloads/) and [Housing Typology 2008](https://data.baltimorecity.gov/Housing-Development/Housing-Typology-2008-Shape/hcv4-ck7s). I am trying to find correlation between two geometries present in those datasets. Data information:

Vital Signs: 55 rows

Housing Typology: 710 rows

I want to find which row of Housing Typology belongs to Vital Signs. And both use different SRIDs as well:

```
SELECT Find_SRID('baltimore', 'vs14_housing', 'geom');
> 102685
SELECT Find_SRID('baltimore', 'housing_typology_2008', 'geom');
> 2248
```

And when I executed the following query:

```
select 
a.gid as Vital_Sign_Index, b.gid as Housing_Typology_Index
from
    baltimore."housing_typology_2008" b, baltimore."vs14_housing" a 
    where
    ST_Intersects(ST_Transform(a.geom, 2248), b.geom)
    order by b.gid
```

It returns something like this:

```
vital_sign_index  housing_typology_index    
51  1
55  1
51  2
55  2
55  3
51  3
55  4
51  4
55  5
51  5
51  6
```

Put I want to do one on one mapping rather than many to one based on maximum intersection with that geometry. So in simple words, I want to **group by based on maximum overlapping distance.**

Currently it returns 1255 records due to overlapping regions while I want it to return 710 (Numbers of Housing Typology rows).

Comment: You seem to be conflating mulipolygon and one-to-many relationships -- the two are not related. Please **edit** your title to focus on the question. Have tried using a GROUP BY in your query?

Comment: I've read your question 3 times and still am not clear what exactly you're trying to calculate. Maybe draw up a picture.

Answer (score 1):

The below query will give you at most one vital_sign_index for each housing topology.   It will give you the vital index such that the intersection is biggest for that topology.  The NOT ST_Touches is just to weed out those where the boundaries touch but no area intersects since intersection is a much costlier process than relation checks.

```
   SELECT DISTINCT ON(b.gid)
        a.gid as Vital_Sign_Index, b.gid as Housing_Typology_Index
     FROM
       baltimore.housing_typology_2008 b
              INNER JOIN    baltimore.vs14_housing a 
        ON (
           ST_Intersects(ST_Transform(a.geom, 2248), b.geom) 
     AND NOT ST_Touches(ST_Transform(a.geom, 2248), b.geom) )
        ORDER BY b.gid,    
        ST_Area( ST_Intersection(ST_Transform(a.geom, 2248), b.geom) ) DESC;
```